# Copying raster data from QgsRasterDataProvider to OpenCV matrix?

Tags: qgis, raster, c++, qt

I'm using C++ (QtCreator) QGIS 2.0 und openCV2 on an 64 bit Workstation running Debian Wheezy. The Application I try to assemble is a standalone QGIS one and will be a mix of gis and image processing software.

Problem description:

I've a QgsMapLayerCanvas with an associated QgsRasterlayer based on an GeoTiff with UTM32 CRS and a resolution of 2 cm. My objective ist to point on an location, determin the pixel data and cut out the data buffer in a 2 x 2 meter window . In the next step this buffer should go to an opencv image processing routine. I' havent found a ready to use solution in the qgis library.

My guess is, that the QgsRasterDataProvider can do this job but. But I cannot find any useful snippets in the web for this task.

Is there somebody who has experience with this matter?

---

Here the snippet of my first try:

```cpp
void MainWindow::doMapImgCanvasClicked(const QgsPoint &point,
                                  Qt::MouseButton button) {


    if (!(qgsMapImgLayer && qgsMapImgProvider) ) return;

    // Size of the window for the image process
    int winWidth  = 10; int winHeight = 10;

    // Calculate the pixel position
    QPoint pixPos(-1,-1);
    doMapImgCalcRasterPos(point, qgsMapImgLayer, pixPos);

    // Give me a response for coords and pixel pos 
    QString str;
    str.sprintf("COORD %f %f PIX %d %d", 
                       point.x(), point.y(),
           pixPos.x(), pixPos.y());
    outLog(str);

    // Create a region of interest
    QgsRectangle roi(point.x()-1, point.y()-1, point.x()+1, point.y()+1);
                // Make a copy of Data 2x2 m for the first band
    QgsRasterBlock *block = qgsMapImgProvider->block(
      1, roi, winWidth, winHeight);

     // Block data is OK?
    if (block->isValid()) { 
        outLog("VALID");
    }

                // Blockdata empty?
    if (block->isEmpty()) { 
      outLog("EMPTY");
    } else { 
     return;
    }

    // Is this the buffer?   
    char* bits = block->bits();
    str.sprintf("DB.TYPE %d", block->dataType()); outLog(str);

    // OK This is the size of the Pointer 
    str.sprintf("DB.NUM %d", sizeof(bits) ); outLog(str);

    // Test Output
    for (int i=0; i<winWidth*winHeight; i++) {
            char c = bits[i];
        str.sprintf("PIX[%d]=%d", i, bits[i] ); outLog(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution:

```cpp
/** Conversation of a QGIS RasterLayer data block to a OpenCV Matrix.
 *
 * Remarks:
 *   Only 3 channel byte ased raster data are accepted.
 *
 * @param point - Center position of the patch
 * @param radius - How many meters around the center position we interested
 * @param width  - Width of the CV::Mat
 * @param height  - Height of the CV::Mat
 *
 * @returns an OperationCode
 *   1 OK, the CV object is the member Variable cv::Mat *cvImageBird;
 * -10 raster data provider is empty
 * -20 less or more than 3 channels
 * -30 raster data are not byte based
 * -110 raster data are not byte based at the 1. band
 * -120 raster data are not byte based at the 2. band
 * -130 raster data are not byte based at the 3. band
 * -(2|3|4)10 raster data block invalid at the 1. band
 * -(2|3|4)20 raster data block invalid at the 2. band
 * -(2|3|4)30 raster data block invalid at the 3. band
 *     -2?0  block is valid?
 *     -3?0  block is empty?
 *     -4?0  data bits are empty?
 */
int CnsMapCanvas::mapImg2CV( const QgsPoint& point,
                             double radius, int width, int height) {

    // RasteDataProvider is valid?
    if ( !qgsProvider) return -10; //error code -10

    // Do we have a 3 channels?
    int numBand   = qgsProvider->bandCount();
    if (numBand != 3) return -20;  //error code -20

    // Do we have a byte based sampling?
    QGis::DataType dataType  = qgsProvider->dataType(1);
    if (dataType != QGis::Byte) return -30; //error code -23

    // OK we have a RGB Image!
    // Create the region of interest
    QgsRectangle roi(point.x()-radius, point.y()-radius,
                     point.x()+radius, point.y()+radius);

    // OpenCV member Variable cv::Mat *cvImageBird;
    // free mem if the OPenCV image is assigned
    if (cvImageBird) delete cvImageBird;

    // Create a new on RGB
    cvImageBird = new cv::Mat3b(width, height, CV_8UC3);

    // Iterate over the bands
    for (int band = 0; band < numBand; ++band) {

        // Request data band homogenity?
        if (dataType != qgsProvider->dataType(band+1)) {
             return -100*(band+1)-10; // error codes -110, -120, -130
        }

        // Get the a proper raster block
        QgsRasterBlock *block = qgsProvider->block(band+1, roi, width, height);
        if (!block->isValid()) {
             return -200*(band+1)-10; // error codes -210, -220, -230
        }

        if (block->isEmpty())  {
             return -400*(band+1)-10; // error codes -310, -320, -330
        }

        // Get the data of the raster block
        char *bits = block->bits();
        if (! bits )  {
            return -400*(band+1)-10; // error codes -410, -420, -430
        }

        // Copy the data block into the CV Object
        for (int col=0; col<width; col++) {
            for (int row=0; row<height; row++) {
                cvImageBird->at<cv::Vec3b>(col,row)[band] = *bits;
                bits++;
            }
        }

        // Free mem the qgsDataBlock
        delete block;
    } // eof for(int band...)

    // set a flag, that we have a proper result;
    return 1;
} // eof mapImg2CV(...)
```

Comment: Use [GDAL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/1.11.1) or [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/)

Comment: Hm, the link scikit-image is dead?! But opencv 3.0 can handle GDAL stuff directly.....